# SQL update x and y records where id=z with ordering by most recent record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a site that needs to use a specific user id and and needs to update 2 columns.

I have tried.

```
UPDATE table SET recordOne = 1 
AND SET recordTwo = 2 
order by latestRecord desc 
WHERE uid = 1 
limit 1
```

And it did not work. Is there anything I am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is what you are missing:

```
UPDATE table
    SET recordOne = 1, 
        recordTwo = 2 
    WHERE uid = 1 
    ORDER BY latestRecord desc 
    LIMIT 1;
```